# Using Php and Sql server in an android application

Tags: php, android, sql-server

Sorry if i am being ignorant but i started reading and learning about php and sql and all the sites i've checked said that php is designed for web.
I want to create a db for my android application, Can anyone clear my confusion and tell me, should i learn php in order to create a database server for my android application?

Thx.

Comment: You should start to learn PHP and mySql. Becuase you will use both to interact with the data and the application.

Comment: you should learn PHP as well as MYSQL. and You can can understand the basic things in both of them.And also we can easily connect with SQL and Android App. There are some DLL are available You can Use that based on Your Versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has absolutely nothing to do with the database layer. Your database is a completely stand alone software which is not written in PHP or has anything to do with the PHP language.

> Php is designed for web

No PHP can be used to write CLI programs its not just for the web.

You can use any database you like, SQL Server, MySql, Marner DB, Postgres, SQLite, Oracle DB, Mongo DB, Couch DB to name a few. Pick which everyone suites your needs the most and use that.